# How to move a sprite device-independent along the x-axis (libgdx)

Tags: android, animation, libgdx, sprite

I've a Sprite that I draw in the render method, I also set the position (x and y) on the screen there while drawing.

The render method looks like this for me (Doesn't work with the try and catch below and it would not be device independent):

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.draw(backgroundgame,  0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    game.batch.draw(car.sprite, xcar,
            (ycar));
    game.batch.end();
    /*try {
        xcar++;
        this.wait(50);
        game.batch.end();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
}
```

In the consructor of the class I set the x and y-position of the sprite.

I was just wondering how I can move the sprite along the x-axis device-independent? Can I do it in the render method or do I need a new Thread for the Sprite?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please carefully read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every frame, if you want to move the sprite along x axis, do:

```
sprite.setposition(lastx + 1*Gdx.graphics.getdeltatime(), some y) 
lastx = sprite.getX()
```

**And do not do** batch.draw() instead use sprite.draw(batch). Batch.draw uses sprite as a dumb texture with no position. With sprite.draw, it does all the position and size drawing for you.

And threading in games is a bad thing to do. Never use threads unless you absolutely need to. 
I. E. Loading something

Everything in games is done each frame(using the main thread). Or else you get sync issues with other threads and it becomes a mess.

And that's why you get fps drops and lag in games if your hardware cannot run them, because the time to process all the commands per frame becomes noticeable.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you mark my question as a correct awnser? By clicking the little check mark, so it becomes green.